# setRepeating() doesn't repeat properly

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager

I'm using the `AlarmManager` to fire a notification daily in specific time which is selected via time picker. The notification fired correctly in the same day but doesn't repeat correctly every day!!!

This is the method for setting the notification using `setRepeating()`:

```
public void witer_reminder(View view)
{
    am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Witer_Notification.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                                    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calSet = (Calendar) cal.clone();

    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, picker.getCurrentHour());
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, picker.getCurrentMinute());
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    if(calSet.compareTo(cal) <= 0)
    {
        // Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
        calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(),
                                            24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

and this is the `BroadcastReciver` class:

```
public class Witer_Notification extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    NotificationManager nm;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                                    new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

        PendingIntent actiontIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                                    new Intent(context, Suggestion.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(""));

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        // mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle());

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                        context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

BTW, the application target is SDK 19.

Comment: Have you read through the `AlarmManager` doc? Exact alarms have to be treated differently if you're running on Kitkat and targeting api 19.

Comment: Yes I read it but I found that the setExact() replacing to set() and it's not applicable for intervalAtMilis as a parameter, and I didn't find anything for setRepeating() @A--C

Comment: Yes, there is no `setExactRepeating` method. Instead, do what the doc says, use `setExact()` and when your `BroadcastReceiver` is called, use `setExact()` to set the alarm again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found that the setExact() replacing to set()

Correct.

> it's not applicable for intervalAtMilis as a parameter

Not directly. But, when you get control in your `BroadcastReceiver` from the `setExact()` event, call `setExact()` again to schedule the next event.

> I didn't find anything for setRepeating()

There is no simple solution, because Google is trying to point out to you that this is bad for the battery. Using `setExact()` as described above is your only option for exact repeating.